# convert video file to .ogg

Tags: media, encoding, video-conversion, ogg-vorbis

I've been having trouble with this because I'm new to Linux:
I would like to convert different video formats to ogv.  I found some terminal commands like this: `ffmpeg -i input.avi -acodec libvorbis -ac 1 -b 768k output.ogg`

The problem with these type of commands is that they are intended to change bit rate, fps, or even resolution.  I would like to just change the file format without changing anything else about the video.

I looked at the man pages for `ffmpeg` and found some useful info but I don't know how to space command-line options.

Are there any easy ways to do this?  In addition, is there a command to change the bit rate so that it doesn't go over a certain rate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out here is the command

```
ffmpeg -y -i '/media/some/file.mkv' -s 1920x1080\
 -aspect 16:9 -r 25 -b 18550k -bt 22792k -vcodec libtheora \
 -acodec libvorbis -ac 2 -ar 48000 -ab 320k lol.ogg
```

**-b** is target bit rate 
**-bt** is like max bit rate 
**-ac** 2 -ar 48000  is stereo 48 kHz 
**-ab** is audio bit rate

Answer (score 5):

You can simply run this to do the conversion.

```
ffmpeg -i neha.avi -acodec libvorbis output.ogg
```

Dont bother to put any options for bitrate or aspect ratio. It will choose for itself.
You can set the max audio bitrate to 192000 (or whatever value you want, upto 320000 AFAIK) by adding `-ab 192000` anywhere in the command. Also, you set the video bitrate at say, 1200kb (or any other value), by including `-b 1200kb` in the command.

So here is the command in the end, (the order of options dont matter, since you asked. nothing to worry)

```
ffmpeg -i neha.avi -acodec libvorbis -ab 192000 -b 1200kb output.ogg
```

[Here](http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/19-ffmpeg-commands-for-all-needs) is a good guide to all that you might want to do.

Comment: thank you for the reply
I will try but 192000kb is less then my source file has can I rise the value

Comment: You sure can. Also, reading the manual (`man ffmpeg`) is very easy. Just try out.

Comment: If it works, consider Accepting the answer so if anyone else sees, they'll know. Ffmpeg is ultra-powerful, good luck with it!

Comment: sadly non of this works same problem it just does it's own thing does not cars what I tell it to do

Comment: sorry my video has 25mb+ video bit rate and 1.2 mb is just not enough as a top value

Comment: The value can be anything, @Levan. You can change it to whatever you want.

Comment: ffmpeg -i '/media/levan/BEEA60D8EA608E89/w8/CIMG8599_1.avi' -acodec libvorbis -ab 192000 -b 226304k ~/test.ogg this is a commend i tried  
yes it encoded but from a 221 Mbps I got  8 200 Kbps

Answer (score 1):

I don't usually use the terminal for my audio/video conversions. I guess that's one area where I like to stick to the GUI.

There's a Windows application called [Format Factory](http://format-factory.en.softonic.com/), and it runs well in WINE. Once you install it, the left side of the window has all the conversion options. I think it's pretty self-explanatory from there. I hope that works!

Comment: thank you for the answer but I want one to one conversion of files  and can it convert video files ??

Comment: yes, Format Factory does all sorts of conversions. Video, Audio, Picture, and you can even rip DVDs with it. As far as one to one conversion, I'm not entirely sure what you mean (probably just my noobiness) but I've always found it to work well for everything I need to do.

Comment: There is a very powerful tool to do this, and you can do it using a terminal. Why not when you can? Refer my answer.

Comment: person who edited my question chopped it up so bad that it is hard to understand what was my question. I want same fps, video/audio bit rate, resolution, aspect ratio

Comment: Saw your original question. You can just not specify all the options, and it'll pick them for itself.

Comment: My source file has 25 mb of video bit rate 30 fps and 384 kb of audio 
 when i use ffmpeg it just lowers the video and audio bit rate and I do not want that I want my quality to be as good as the source

Answer (score 1):

http://www.iasptk.com/ff-multi-converter-is-a-simple-graphical-application-which-enables-you-to-convert-audio-video-image-and-document-files-between-all-popular-formats

**FF Multi Converter is a simple graphical application which enables you to convert audio, video, image and document files between all popular formats, using and combining other programs. It uses ffmpeg for audio/video files, unoconv for document files and PythonMagick library for image file conversions.**

The goal of FF Multi Converter is to gather all multimedia types in one application and provide conversions for them easily through a user-friendly interface. Extra options will be gradually added.

The application is written in python and PyQt.

All code is licensed under the GNU General Public License.

FF Multi Converter is free software - software that respects your freedom.

Features

Conversions for several file formats.

Very easy to use interface.

Access to common conversion options.

Options for saving and naming files.

Recursive conversions.

**Installing on Ubuntu and Debian**

Stable release

To add the ppa to your system resources and install ffmulticonverter, open a terminal and enter:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ffmulticonverter/stable

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install ffmulticonverter
```

Answer (score 1):

I found pretty useful `ffmpeg2theora`, which kept original video's quality (full HD), launching the command

```
ffmpeg2theora in_file.mkv -o out_file.ogg
```